Do we not vote enough?
For awhile now I've been looking at other StackExchange sites in the beta and I think we don't vote enough. We have some questions that reach 20 or even 40 upvotes, but a vast majority don't even reach 10. Now looking at sites like Workplace SE, being in beta for half of the time we have. Even on their front page we can see a lot of high voting questions, not to mention their overall scores.
I know that we shouldn't be comparing ourselves to other sites, but I still feel that the Bitcoin SE community doesn't vote enough.
Do you think that we should try to promote the "vote early, vote often" mentality more so on this StackExchange? Are there any other issues you think are contributing to our low amount of votes? Any opinion or idea is welcome.

Yeah, I think that we should vote more. I'm a bit lazy with that myself but apparently I'm in 12th place so yes, we could definitely vote more. So how do we promote it?

@D.H. Hmm, maybe we should post something on the Bulletin Board? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board . It could keep reminding people to vote early and vote often. Asides that, I guess we should be shining as an example.

@D.H.-bitcoin.se: Funnily enough you're still ranked 30th even today. :'(

I agree that this is important so I took ThePiachu's suggestion of using the bulletin board and made the Vote early, vote often! post "featured". That post is now visible on the site's bulletin board.

Hmm, by the way, how many questions can you feature? It would probably also be beneficial to give some exposure to this one in order to show people that we are having some small problem.
